# Kafka with Zookeeper 3.5.7 Crash NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()

Tags: java, macos, apache-kafka, homebrew, apache-zookeeper

I am facing this error stream

```
2020-03-10 13:43:33 NIOServerCnxnFactory [ERROR] Thread Thread[NIOWorkerThread-7,5,main] died
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:331)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$IOWorkRequest.doWork(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:530)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WorkerService$ScheduledWorkRequest.run(WorkerService.java:155)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
...
```

using Java version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

I am facing this problem when starting kafka `2.4.0` with zookeeper `3.5.7` on local mac Os Catalina, installed with homebrew. How to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's explained in other service like [hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/14214) and [dopio](https://github.com/plasma-umass/doppio/issues/497) that this was caused by backward compatibility issue from jdk 9 to jdk 8.

There are 2 obvious options, either you:

1. Update your jdk to 9
2. Downgrade your zookeeper to `3.4.x`

I chose to downgrade my zookeeper to `3.4.14` by using:

```
# force install zookeeper first
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6d8197bbb5f77e62d51041a3ae552ce2f8ff1344/Formula/zookeeper.rb

# then force install kafka compatible with zookeeper 3.4.14
brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6d8197bbb5f77e62d51041a3ae552ce2f8ff1344/Formula/kafka.rb
```

Comment: Kafka works with Java 11, and comes with a compatible Zookeeper...

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall 3.5.7's zookeeper with brew with `brew uninstall zookeeper`, and then install 3.4.14's zookeeper

Download link from https://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html or https://mirrors.cnnic.cn/apache/zookeeper